# Big zero sum game matrix

Tags: nash-equilibrium

I've been trying to solve a nash equilibrium for a game. The game is zero sum and symmetric. Unfortunately, it is also quite large. The payoff matrix is (n! , n!) in size. To simplify, I used n=4 (the game is easily solved for n<4) and I've tried cutting out strictly dominated strategies. This is where I am stuck. I suspect that there are additional dominant strategies, but I can't find them. The result is an 11x11 payoff matrix for player A. (Since the game is zero sum, player B has a similar payoff matrix). How do I reduce this game further?

\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&-1&1&-1
\\-1&0&1&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&-1
\\-1&-1&0&-1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0
\\-1&-1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1&-1&0
\\-1&0&-1&-1&0&-1&1&0&0&0&0
\\0&-1&-1&-1&1&0&1&0&1&0&1
\\-1&0&0&-1&-1&-1&0&1&1&1&1
\\-1&-1&-1&-1&0&0&-1&0&1&1&1
\\1&0&0&-1&0&-1&-1&-1&0&1&1
\\-1&-1&0&1&0&0&-1&-1&-1&0&1
\\1&1&0&0&0&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1&0
\end{bmatrix}

If you are curious, the matrix was derived from a game called goofspiel.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/gamesolve.html

An optimal strategy for Player I is:
 (0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
An optimal strategy for Player II is:
 (0.33333,0,0,0.16667,0,0.33333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.16667,0,0,0,0,0)

...odd. I would think that player 2 and player 1 would have identical mixed strategies.